# Ruby - Creating token numbers for visitors and reusing them

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure how to write a ruby program that takes user input and creates a token for them. The clinic accepts 20 walkins per day. For example, if John walks in, the receptionist will create a new record, enter John's details and auto generate a token upon save. This happens every time a person walks in.

Now, if someone cancels, I would like to remove their entry from file and use that empty slot to accomodate the next walk in (say, if number 6 cancels and there are 11 already issued tokens, the 12th walkin gets the token 6). Presently I'm writing these details (except for tokens) to a text file and I am not sure how to implement the token system. Is an array the right way to go or a hash?

Comment: Why do your tokens need to be reusable? Is there a shortage of integers in mathematics?

Comment: @CodeGnome because you must be green and kind to the environment. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

A good model for this use case is a "token bucket." The idea is that you have a fixed capacity represented by tokens that can be taken from, or put back into, your pool of resources by another object. The holder of a token is then eligible to consume whatever resource the token represents. In your case, the tokens would represent the ability to take a walk-in appointment slot.

There are a number of ways to implement this in code. What follows is one example taken from my [token_bucket.rb repository](https://github.com/CodeGnome/token_bucket.rb) on GitHub. The source code is available under GPLv3 if you want to extend it.

### An Example TokenBucket Class

The TokenBucket has a pool of tokens stored in an instance variable, and provides callers a public interface through the TokenBucket#get_token and TokenBucket#put_token methods. For example:

```
class TokenBucket
  def initialize tokens=20
    @tokens = tokens
  end

  def get_token
    if tokens?
      @tokens -= 1
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def put_token
    @tokens += 1
    false
  end

  private

  def tokens?
    @tokens > 0
  end
end
```

### Using the TokenBucket

The token bucket is used by a collaborator object; the collaborator requests/returns tokens and tracks which objects are currently holding valid tokens. In this model, the tokens themselves are never actually passed around, and collaborators shouldn't care how the token bucket implements them internally.

In this case, we'll use an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) of [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Struct.html) objects to collaborate with the [TokenBucket](https://github.com/CodeGnome/token_bucket.rb/blob/master/token_bucket.rb).

```
require 'pp'

# Set up a token bucket to represent a single appointment slot to contend for,
# and define an Array of Structs to act as the collaborator object.
tb = TokenBucket.new 1
Person = Struct.new :name, :token
people = [Person.new('John Doe'), Person.new('Jane Doe')]

# John and Jane both try to schedule an appointment.
people[0].token = tb.get_token
people[1].token = tb.get_token

# Who has a token, and is thus eligible to make an appointment?
pp people.select { |person| person.token }
#=> [#<struct Person name="John Doe", token=true>]

# John cancels an appointment and Jane takes the token.
people[0].token = tb.put_token
people[1].token = tb.get_token

# Who has a token, and is thus eligible to make an appointment?
pp people.select { |person| person.token }
#=> [#<struct Person name="Jane Doe", token=true>]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like a UUID for the token (and not something dependent on the details entered) then it sounds like a good candidate for a Hash key. You will also need a separate array to order the tokens. So here is my example:

```
walk_ins = {
  "e6ab9d40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c" => wakin_in_one_details,
  "ff7b9f40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c" => wakin_in_two_details,
  "001b2c80-3c62-0132-0205-28373700b71c" => wakin_in_three_details
}
```

And the array

```
todays_slots = ["e6ab9d40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c", "ff7b9f40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c", "001b2c80-3c62-0132-0205-28373700b71c"]
```

Then walk in two cancels

```
walk_ins["ff7b9f40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c"] = nil
```

And someone else comes in

```
walk_ins["ff7b9f40-3c61-0132-0205-28373700b71c"] = wakin_in_four_details
```